# Is there a way in javascript to find the coordinates of text within a div?

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, web-scraping

For instance, I'm looking to find the coordinates of the text "The" in this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagles_(band)) after it is rendered, much like the coordinates given by chrome's developer view. [Screenshot of developer options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rc5k4.png)

```
    <div>The <b>Eagles</b> are an American <a href="/wiki/Rock_music" title="Rock music">rock</a> band formed in Los Angeles in 1971. With five number-one singles and six number-one albums, six <a href="/wiki/Grammy_Award" class="mw-redirect" title="Grammy Award">Grammy Awards</a> and five <a href="/wiki/American_Music_Award" class="mw-redirect" title="American Music Award">American Music Awards</a>, the Eagles were one of the most successful musical acts of the 1970s in North America. Founding members <a href="/wiki/Glenn_Frey" title="Glenn Frey">Glenn Frey</a> (guitars, vocals), <a href="/wiki/Don_Henley" title="Don Henley">Don Henley</a> (drums, vocals), <a href="/wiki/Bernie_Leadon" title="Bernie Leadon">Bernie Leadon</a> (guitars, vocals) and <a href="/wiki/Randy_Meisner" title="Randy Meisner">Randy Meisner</a> (bass guitar, vocals) were recruited by <a href="/wiki/Linda_Ronstadt" title="Linda Ronstadt">Linda Ronstadt</a> as band members, some touring with her, and all playing on her <a href="/wiki/Linda_Ronstadt_(album)" title="Linda Ronstadt (album)">third solo album</a>, before venturing out on their own on <a href="/wiki/David_Geffen" title="David Geffen">David Geffen</a>'s new <a href="/wiki/Asylum_Records" title="Asylum Records">Asylum Records</a> label. </div>
```

I've already tried innerHTML (element.innerHTML) which just returns the size of the div, and a few other things, but nothing seems to be quite right.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant HTML and your code trials please.

Comment: What you see in that Wiki page is not coordinates, it's the size. But yes, it is possible to get both, the coordinates and the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `createRange()` function to select your text from the article. *This function selects Nodes*.

Assuming that you're using this wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagles_(band), you will have to use the 7th paragraph of the page.

```
// Getting the 7th HTML paragraph element
const paragraphElement = document.querySelector('p:nth-child(7)');

const range = document.createRange();
range.setStart(paragraphElement , 0);
// Selecting the first Node only
range.setEnd(paragraphElement, 1);
const rects = range.getClientRects();

// The node location is in the rects object
console.log(rects);
```